# Easy way to pipe data between processes outside of main pipeline in bash

Tags: bash, file-descriptor, mkfifo

I want to be able to pipe data between processes in an existing bash pipeline. To illustrate better what I mean, take this trivial example, where I assume that file descriptor 3 is acting like a fifo.

```
seq 5 | tee >(while read num; do echo $(($num * $num)); done >&3) | paste - <(<&3 cat)
```

I want this to output

```
1   1
2   4
3   9
4   16
5   25
```

and then terminate. Ideally, the solution would be something like `exec 3<>-`, where bash would open file descriptor three as a read write buffer. As far as I can tell there is no support for this in bash, so I turned to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/184307/bash-create-anonymous-fifo) for creating anonymous pipes. Based off of that discussion, I came up with this function:

```
function temp_pipe() {
  [[ "$1" =~ [3-9] ]] || return 1
  PIPE_DIR="$(mktemp -d)"
  PIPE="$PIPE_DIR/pipe"
  mkfifo "$PIPE"
  eval "exec $1<>'$PIPE'"
  rm -f "$PIPE"
  rmdir "$PIPE_DIR"
}
```

which takes a file descriptor as an argument, and attaches it to an anonymous fifo. This in principle works, but I can't figure out how to close the fifo when I'm done writing output to it. The following works almost as intended:

```
temp_pipe 3 && seq 5 | tee >(while read num; do echo $(($num * $num)); done >&3) | paste - <(<&3 cat)
```

in that it outputs the correct result, but paste stays open because file descriptor 3 is never closed. I naively thought I could append `exec 3>&-` to end of the subprocess to close the file descriptor and have everything work out as expected, but that doesn't work. The parent file descriptor is not closing because the close operation is running in a child process, and so is closing the inherited reference to the same descriptor, instead of closing the descriptor in the parent process.

I'm ideally looking for a solution where it'll be relatively easy to build complex pipelines without a lot of manual management of temporary fifos or file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
    seq 5 | while read i; do printf '%d\t%d\n' "$i" "$((i*i))"; done
```

produces the desired output, but I doubt it is what you want because `seq` is the parent process and closes the pipe. If I understand your question, you have a situation where `while` is the parent process and other process(es) are writing information to the pipe.

I believe your problem lies in the fact that the bash `read` will wait for indefinitely for input from a pipe because a pipe does not have an end.

- You can use `read -t` to define a timeout where, without input, the `while` loop assumes there is no more input.
- You can logically declare than when the while loop reads "", then the while loop will exit.
- You may be able to push control characters into the stream to indicate end of file (Control-D).
- You can send specific signals to the parent process and trap them.

I searched for this question because I am creating a bash daemon which I would like to be able to control via a pipe. I am planning to use a standard file descriptor because `systemctl` will tell me the PID of the daemon, then its stdin is at /proc/$PID/fd/0. This way I can calculate the name of the pipe instead of explicitly creating a named pipe. I could also run tests using the terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember the original use case, pasting two streams together was just meant as an example. I'm not sure read is problem in the example though, because the subprocess read is in should finish. It just doesn't close the named pip in the process. However, it does feel like using the raw file descriptors might work in some circumstances.